# What does “diddled-eyed Joe to a damned-if-I-know” mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, reservoir-dogs

In the scene from *Reservoir Dogs* (1992), where Holdaway meets Orange in the restaurant, Orange informs him
that he is now part of Joe’s team.

> Holdaway: If this crook’s a Brewers fan, his ass has gotta be from
> Wisconsin.  I’ll bet you everything from a **diddled-eyed Joe to a
> damned-if-I-know**, that  Milwaukee got a sheet on this Mr White’s
> ass.

The same phrase is used in the movie [True Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Romance), which was written by Tarantino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read somewhere that "*it's a 'Tarantinoism'*".

> **Drexl Spivey**: Grab a seat, boy. Grab yourself an egg roll. We got everything here from a diddle-eyed-Joe to a damned-if-I-know. [True Romance](https://wiki.tarantino.info/index.php/Drexl_Spivey)

To me, it just means that they have everything you could possibly want to eat. In Reservoir Dogs, that's probably the same meaning: I'd bet **everything** I have (and you can think of) that I'm right.

As Drexl has a dead eye and portraits himself as an African-American, I've always wondered if it was a kind of play-on-word/reference to [Cotton-Eyed Joe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton-Eyed_Joe#19th_century) (because that song was sung by people in plantations).

'*Damned-if-I-know*' is a pretty [standard expression](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/damned+if+I+know), but I never found a good translation/reference of the '*diddle-eyed-Joe*' part, so I have to go with my understanding of it, it probably has to be taken with a grain of salt... (or corrected by a native speaker.)

As Tarantino always adds many references to himself/others, it's quite difficult to know why he did use the expression again. He may have loved the [1972 movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10319904/)...